# how to define a self customized cout?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
std::streambuf buf;
ostream mycout(&buf);
mycout << "Hellow, World!" << endl;
```

I use the above statements to initialize an instance of ostream. I want "mycout" works exactly as "std::cout" all the output will display to STDOUT(Screen). Above code do not work. Compiled error:

```
'std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_streambuf': cannot access protected member declared in class 'std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Could you please explain why you can't just use `std::cout`?

Comment: 1. To understand how std::cout works. As far as I know, cout is just an instance of ostream. Like a variable. But I can't define myself of xxcout as an instance of ostream. 2. I want write a "tcout" which is an instance of ostream when character set is ASCII, and is an instance of wostream when character set is UTF-16. I search all the articles online. Most people say there is no solutions to write a generic code for both ASCII/UTF-16 in Windows Console program.

Comment: I can't help you with (1), but the correct way to deal with (2) is to write your program so that it uses *only* the `W`-suffixed Windows APIs ... but does *absolutely everything else* with narrow strings and streams, containing UTF-8. Convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16 as necessary to call into Windows, and immediately convert back afterward. Do not use `tchar.h`, do not use the `A` functions, do not use the unsuffixed functions, and do not write UTF-16 into new files. I believe there is a `#define` you can set that makes `windows.h` only supply the W functions, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: (add'l): Re "no solution to write a generic code for ASCII/UTF-16 in ...": **you don't need to do that**. The narrow APIs in Windows are, AIUI, preserved *only* for backward compatibility with Windows 9x. You should never need to use them in new code.

Comment: But I need to write a console application portable between linux and windows.

Comment: Oh, well, on Linux you just read and write UTF-8.  This is (part of) why you avoid using UTF-16 anywhere but immediately around Windows API calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it work exactly as std::cout, you can construct it using the streambuf of cout directly:

```
std::ostream mycout{std::cout.rdbuf()};
```

But for real applications you should probably think twice if you want to do this, since it either provides no benefit over using std::cout or forces people to use always mycout instead of std::cout which they might not be used to/forget/...

Comment: Thanks, it works! With following preprocessing code, it can switch back and forth between UTF-8/UTF-16:#ifdef UNICODE
typedef basic_string<wchar_t, char_traits<wchar_t>, allocator<wchar_t> > tstring;
std::wostream tcout{ std::wcout.rdbuf() };
#else
typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > tstring;
std::ostream tcout{ std::cout.rdbuf() };
#endif